# .tag file extension not picking color theme in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsp-tags

In my project files with extension, .jsp are picking up the color theme of vs code, but the files with " .tag " extension are showing code as plain text.

A similar problem occurred with the .vue extension but was solved after installing the vetur extension in vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through this, and in the bottom-right corner of vs code the language support was showing it to "plain text", I just changes it to " java " and it works fine now.